# Adjective/adverb before an adjective + noun

Tags: adjectives, relative-adverbs

Can someone explain the difference between:

> "One *particularly* important influence was the travel diary published
> by Arthur Young…

and

> One *particular* important influence was the travel diary published by
> Arthur Young…

or

"*violent* political conflict" and "*violently* political conflict"?

When to use an adverb which modifies the adjective + noun and when only two adjectives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Particularly important influence" means an influence that was important to a higher degree than other influences.  It is more important than other influences.

"One particular important influence" means one specific important influence.  It does not mean the influence was more important.

"Violent political conflict" means the political conflict was violent.

"Violently political conflict" means the conflict was very political.

When using the adverb in these examples, it is modifying the adjective.  When using the adjective, it is modifying the noun - you could remove the adjective and still have the sentence be meaningful: "violent conflict" or "particular influence."  If you removed the adjective from the adverb examples it would not make sense "violently conflict" or "particularly influence"

Comment: Thank you, Steve V (:  You were very clear!

Answer (score 0):

One particularly important influence

The word "**particularly**" is an adverb, which in this case means it modifies the adjective "important". So here, "particularly important" means roughly the same as "very important" or "especially important".

The word "**particular**" is an adjective, which means it modifies a noun, in this case, "influence". In this context, "a particular important influence" means "one specific influence that was important".